# How to set the initial position of a BottomSheet?

Tags: android, android-animation, bottom-sheet

Is it possible to to have `BottomSheet` initial position start from approx. middle of screen? instead of having at end of screen?

How can I set that initial position? I want `BottomSheet` (that has a `recyclerView` in it) to appear initially from middle of screen (towards bottom). When user swap it up, it should come up and stop just under my app main Title bar.

Your expert opinion is appreciated.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this. https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: is it possible to disable the overlay shadow when Sheet moves up?